# Find the next country and the parameters

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I created this puzzle.

Denmark = [1 or 4, 11880, 1, 15, 4.433687003, 4 or 5]

India = [11803, 381024, -1, 23, 0.3706062241, 5]

New Zealand = [8916100448256 or 302875106592253, 43680, -1, 40, 0.2362925527, 1]

Norway = [1 or 4, 13832, 1, 29, 5.609984399,5]

Zimbabwe = [4, 15561, -1, 49, 0.5743424584,4]

Find the next country in the sequence and its corresponding parameters.

Hint 1:

> You know what this is. (Yes this is a hint)

Hint 2:

> There may be multiple country names that may come next

Hint 3:

> Where did I write this question?

Hint 4:

> Can you solve this puzzle? (Yes, this also a hint.)

Comment: Interesting question and hints! (+1)

Comment: I can see only one possible connection, in rot13(svryq guerr, jurer zvahf bar vf sbe n pbhagel gung jnf cneg bs gur oevgvfu rzcver, gur bguref jrer abg).